# how to generate 15 million+ data points and insert from node server to mysql with no error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mariadb

I wrote a script that generates 5,443,200 data records in batches of 544,320, which are inserted into a mysql db using the mysqljs/mysql module, and when I try to bump up the volume of data records, I get a node heap out of memory error. I tried to refactor this using a generator and iterator, but doing so seemed to introduce a lot of buggy behavior and ultimately crashed my mysql server. I had also thrown in the cluster node module to see if that would help, but that created issues of my mysql server refusing connections and sometimes crashing my computer altogether.

My question is, how would I be able to scale the script such that I can generate 30 times the 5 million I've generated at ideally the same generation and insertion rate? I reckon I can still work with generators and iterators as it's most likely my particular implementation that's buggy.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bed4a311fb746ba04c65d331d23bd0a8

Comment: Forgot mysql, take mongoDb/NeDb with documents of hundreds arrays inside for each. then concat all this array after you requested them (with find())

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
  initTimes(i);
}` <- this seems like its better to do *one after another* instead of *all at the same time*

Comment: pirs: I don't understand what you mean by 'forgot mysql'. At any rate, I'd like to keep the solution as being related to sql.

jonas: do you mean by 'one after another instead of all' that I should be looking at using promises or callbacks instead of running 10 concurrent processes?

Answer (score 2):

Batch-inserting more than 1000 rows at a time is very much into "diminishing returns".  1000 gives you about 99% of the theoretical maximum.

When you go much beyond 1000, you first get into inefficiencies, then you get (as you found out) into limitations.  Your attempt to get to 100% has backfired.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating what you mean by the percentages?  Also, I'd be fine with keeping the batch sizes at 544,320, which haven't been too problematic, with a pool connection limit of 10.

Comment: 1 row at a time takes 11 units of time; 10 at a time takes 20 units of time; 100 takes 110; 1000 takes 1010; 10000 takes 10010; etc.  Dividing, one gets these "per row":  11, 2, 1.1, 1.01, 1.001, etc.   Theoretically, one can get to 1 row being inserted in 1 unit it of time.  But at 100 rows per insert, it takes 1.01 -- 99% of the theoretical best.  544320 will _probably_ take longer than 544320 units of time due to other factors.